# How to I make my function import and concatenate/merge "all" the files in a folder?

Tags: r, import, merge, concatenation

Due to....limitations I have been forced to download my data manually into one csv file at a time. Until now, this hasn't been an issue. I've saved all off my files in the same folder, so I've been able to use a function so simply merge them (all column names are exactly the same).

I have recently have to download multitudes more data than previously, however. I am currently trying to import/concatenate 513 csv-files at the same time and it seems my function has hit some kind of limit. All csv files are no longer imported, which is of course very disconcerting.

I tried to move the unimported files (together with files that were successfully imported) to another folder, and I could import/concatenate those files just fine. This doesnt seem to have anything to do with the files themselves but with the sheer number of them being imported/concatenated at the same time.

Is there a way to import and concatenate "all" files in a folder with no limitations?

The top 4 and bottom 4 lines in each csv file contains metadata and needs to be disregarded. Until now I've been using the following loop to import/concatenate my files:

```
setwd("path")
file_list<-list.files("path")
for (file in file_list){

  # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
  if (!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- head(read_delim(file, delim=';',na="",skip=4),-4)
  }

  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dataset")){
    temp_dataset <-head(read_delim(file, delim=';',na="",skip=4),-4)
    dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base `R`, you would use `do.call(rbind, list_data)`. With `data.table`, you can use `data.table::rbindlist` that will be more efficient.

## `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
setwd("path")
file_list<-list.files("path")
list_data <- lapply(file_list, function(file) head(fread(file, delim=';',na="",skip=4),-4))
df <- rbindlist(list_data, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
```

I added the arguments `fill = TRUE` and `use.names = TRUE` to be safe: you lose a little bit of efficiency here but you are sure you rbind columns at the place they should be.

## Base R

```r
setwd("path")
file_list<-list.files("path")
list_data <- lapply(file_list, function(file) head(read_delim(file, sep=';',na.strings = "", skip=4),-4))
df <- do.call(rbind, list_data)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can use lapply that way though, it tells me that "Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default"?

Comment: I had forgotten the first argument (the file list).  Sorry about that

Comment: The base R solution seems to work but the one with data.table tells me that " Error in fread(file, delim = ";", na = "", skip = 4) : unused argument (delim = ";") "?

I will accept this answer anyway but I'm just being thorough :)

Comment: Thanks ! You're totally right, I will correct to give you a good answer with `data.table` (approach I prefer). In fact the argument is not `delim` but `sep`. Usually you don't even need to provide `sep` argument because you have an automatic detection. I let it in the solution but you can try without. I also corrected to use `na.strings` rather than `na` in `fread` call. Sorry for the typos, I was not able to check help file when I posted the answer.

Comment: Should I interpret this then like 

a) There is a concept called efficiency, and inefficient import functions are bound to make mistakes when importing large numbers of data

b) do.call is more efficient than using a for loop?

Comment: For you **b)** point definitely yes. `for` loops are very inefficient in `R` (too much memory overhead), and there is almost always a way to use a built-in function (at worst, you use `lapply` that is more efficient than `for`). For your **a)** point, it depends. Inefficient functions can provoke errors if they ask more RAM than you have. But, if you don't hit the RAM limit, inefficient functions should only bring you to wait a lot because they are slow.